# When are new kernels in an Ubuntu release?

Tags: 11.04, kernel

Due to a kernel bug I cannot use `2.6.38-11-generic`, so I'm using `2.6.32-28-generic`.

When will there be a new kernel in 11.04?

Comment: can you specify which "new 2.6.38" bersion you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since ubuntu does not follow the [rolling release](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_release) model. No new software except a security update is introduced in the repositories and therefore a new kernel will not be available.

If you still want to use a new kernel release you can try [mainline builds](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds).

Comment: I think he's asking when he's going to get a new 2.6.38 kernel.

Comment: @JorgeCastro the question is not clear enough and if he wants 2.6.38-11-generic then that is already in the repo ( https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/i386/linux-image-2.6.38-11-generic/2.6.38-11.50) :?

Comment: i want the "new 2.6.38" not 2.6.38-11